# How to create a rails api that routes different urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

Am new to rails I want to perform a get request in different urls
such as
 `http://website.com/api/example1`
 `http://website.com/api/example2`
 `http://website.com/api/example3`
 `http://website.com/api/example4`

And how can i set session data to be accessed across all controllers in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add something like following at your `routes.rb`:

```
scope "api",:module => "api" do
  get 'example1' => 'exact_data#example1', :as => 'api_example1'
  get 'example2' => 'exact_data#example2', :as => 'api_example2'
  get 'example3' => 'exact_data#example3', :as => 'api_example3'
end
```

So your controller should have:

```
class Api::ExactDataController < ApplicationController
    def example1 
        #...
    end
    def example2 
        #...
    end
    def example3 
        #...
    end
end
```

If you have common session logic that you want to access and use from all controllers then you can put them at your `application_controller.rb` as by default it is parent of all other controllers that you create.

For example if you put a `current_user` method at ApplicationController then you would have `current_user` method in all your controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

private

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_username(session[:username]) if session[:username]
    end

end
```

Comment: Hi Sadaf, am encountering this error but I don't know how I can resolve it. `You should not use the 'match' method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.`

Comment: updated my answer, you need to use `:via => [:get]` in match.

Comment: Alright it works but still am encountering another different error.  `ActionController::RoutingError at /api/example1`
**uninitialized constant Api**

Comment: do you have a `ApiController`?

Comment: No beside I have `class Api::ExactDataController < ApplicationController`

Comment: I have applied all the changes but still am facing this error  `ActionController::RoutingError at /api/example1`  **uninitialized constant** Api

Comment: I also used `namespace:api do` but still am facing the similar issue `RoutingError`

Comment: did you try `namespace :api, module: "api" do` ?

Comment: I have changed it but still no change
**Here is my route.rb**
 `namespace :api, module:"api" do
    match "example1" => "api#example1", :via=>[:get],:as => "api_example#1"
  end`

**my Controller **
`class ApiController < ApplicationController

  def index
 end

end
`

Comment: In Additional to that in my routes.rb I have `resources :api, only:[:index]`
`

Comment: Ooh at last I have figured it out. I have created  a folder `app/controller/api/` to hold my controller and created another in `app/views/api/api/` to hold my views. And now its `app/views/api/api/example1.html.erb`

And it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your session value in your code as so:

```
session[:some_value] = 'This is a session value'
```

What you do not want to do is store large amounts of data into your session.  This will have huge performance implications.  If you need to store large amounts of data, I would suggest a model to store it in within the database.

Although, I would question why you are setting things in the session for URL access?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions